# what is '...' in java?

Tags: java, parameters

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the ellipsis for in this method signature?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2367398/what-is-the-ellipsis-for-in-this-method-signature)

I saw "T... elements" in java code.
what does that mean?
thanks!

Comment: See [What is the ellipsis for in this method signature?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2367398/what-is-the-ellipsis-for-in-this-method-signature)

Answer (score 7):

It means, you can pass all T variables you want to a method.

If a method is:

```
public void myMethod(String... a)
{

}
```

You can make call with all String objects you want to that method:

```
myMethod("s1");
myMethod("s1", "s2");
myMethod("s1", "s2", "s3");
myMethod("s1", "s2", "s3", "s4");
```

[Here's](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html) Java official documentation on that language feature. It was introduced in **Java 5**.

Answer (score 7):

That is the ['var args' specifier](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Language-Basics/Varargs.htm).

It means that you can pass in 0 or more elements into the method.

You would use it like this:

```
public void method(String str, int... elements) {
    for (int i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        print(str + " " + elements[i];
    }
}
```

and, you can call it like this:

```
method("Hi");
method("He", 1, 2 , 3, 4, 5);
method("Ha", 1 , 2);
int[] arr = {1, 2 , 3 ,3 ,4};
method("Ho", arr);
```

Answer (score 2):

It is a placeholder for an array of T (`T[]`) where the array itself can be specified as t1,t2,t3 etc. where all the ts are of type T.

CF: http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html

Answer (score 2):

It is used in method declaration:

```
void someMethod(String... strings) {
  //blabla method body
}
```

means you can put array of Strings as parameter, or Strings separated by comma. Both calls are valid:

```
someMethod("a", "b", "c");

String[] stringsArray = new String[] {"a", "b", "c"};
some Method(stringsArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

This means that you can pass in 0 or more instances of object T. You can access those parameters as an array.

Example:

```
public void printStrings(String... strings)
{
    for (String string : strings) {
        System.out.println(string);
    }
}
```

You can then call this method using any of these calls:

```
printStrings("one", "two", "three", "four");
printStrings(new String[] { "one", "two", "three", "four" } );
printStrings(/* any array of strings, even an empty array */);
```

In your case. T... means you can pass in any number of instances of type T, which is a generic that should be defined at the top of your class file.