# What are these three dots in parameter types

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the ellipsis for in this method signature?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2367398/what-is-the-ellipsis-for-in-this-method-signature)

For example: `protected void onProgressUpdate(Context... values)`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One word: **[`varargs`.](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html)**

> The three periods after the final parameter's type indicate that the final argument may be passed as an array *or* as a sequence of arguments. Varargs can be used *only* in the final argument position.

Answer (score 5):

They're called varargs, and were introduced in Java 5. Read http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html for more information.

In short, it allows passing an array to a method without having to create one, as if the method took a variable number of arguments. In your example, the following four calls would be valid :

```
onProgressUpdate();
onProgressUpdate(context1);
onProgressUpdate(context1, context2, context3);
onProgressUpdate(new Context[] {context1, context2});
```

Answer (score 2):

Its the `varargs` introduced in java 5. more info at [Varargs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html)

Answer (score 0):

Three dots are called ellipsis. Method can be called any number of values of type Context. You can call that method with no value also.

Answer (score 0):

It means that the `values` argument is an optional array of `Context` objects.  So you could call the "onProgressUpdate" function in the following ways:

```
onProgressUpdate(); // values is an empty array.
onProgressUpdate(new Context[] { new Context() }); // values has one item.
onProgressUpdate(context1, context2); // values has two items.
```

See the [varargs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html) language feature introduced in Java 1.5.

Answer (score 0):

That means that you can put a range of values :

```
onProgessUpdate(c1,c2,c3);
```