# void... params meaning in java function declaration

Tags: java, android, eclipse, adt

I recently came across a java snippet .The function definitions have a different format than what i know till now . Following are the codes-

```
  protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
        Log.i(TAG, "doInBackground");
        //Invoke web method 'PopulateCountries' with dummy value
        invokeJSONWS("dummy","PopulateCountries");
        return null;
    }
```

and a similar function with `...` in the parameter

```
protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onProgressUpdate");
    }
```

What does `...` mean in the following context?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the ellipsis (...) for in this method signature?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2367398/what-is-the-ellipsis-for-in-this-method-signature)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Android's [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) is a generic type.

When you need an async task that has no sense of intermediate progress data, you should declare it as `MyTask extends AsyncTask<Something, Void, Something>` using the class `Void` as the specification of the `Progress` type variable, and, following usual generic rules, if you decide to overwrite `onProgressUpdate` you will have to declare it as `onProgressUpdate(Void... values)`.

Hence `Void...` does not mean anything other than the usual vararg method whose type happened to be `Void`.

Answer (score 28):

> What does ... mean in the following context .

This specifies **variable length argument** when you want to call method with parameters of type say `String` but you don't know how many parameters you want to pass you can use this.

as you can pass any number of `String` to method.

So you can call method like these ways.

for

```
public void met(String...a)
```

you can call this method by

```
ob.met()
ob.met("a")
ob.met("a","b")
```

and so on.

You can read more about it [HERE.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html)

Answer (score 10):

it called `varargs`, and it means an arbitrary number of parameter of the same type. You can access it on per index basis, like an array.

Answer (score 4):

```
type ... variableName
```

The `ellipsis (...)` identifies a variable number of arguments, and
is demonstrated in the following summation method.

```
static int sum (int ... numbers)
{
   int total = 0;
   for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++)
        total += numbers [i];
   return total;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

There is optional parameters with Java 5.0. Just declare your function like this:

```
public void doSomething(boolean...optionalFlag) {
    ...
}
```

you could call with `doSomething()` or `doSomething(true)` now.

This is "new" in Java 1.5 and beyond (not supported in Java 1.4 or earlier).

Answer (score 1):

it is variable length arguments