# How should I zip a List<Observable<T>> into an Observable<List<T>>?

Tags: java, rx-java, rx-java2

I have a `List<Observable<T>>` that I would like to transform into an `Observable<List<T>>`.

I am aware of `Observable.zip`, which seems like the right function, but I'm not sure how to define the `zipper` parameter.

Here is what I have tried:

```
final List<Observable<T>> tasks = getTasks();

final Observable<List<T>> task = Observable.zip(
    tasks, 
    x -> ImmutableList.copyOf(x)
        .stream()
        .map(x -> (T)x)
        .collect(ImmutableList.toImmutableList()));
```

However, this requires an unchecked cast.

How should I go about this in RxJava 2?

---

Note that [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43524709/rxjava-zip-list-of-observable) refers to RxJava 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the primitives:

```
List<Observable<T>> tasks = getTasks();
Observable<List<T>> task = Observable.merge(tasks).toList();
```

However, do you *really* need all the tasks at once? You could skip the `toList` and proccess the tasks as they come; this will give you both better responsiveness and easier concurrency control.

Comment: I have a list of files to download and I want to wait for all to succeed or one to fail.

Comment: Then you don't need `toList` - process them one-by-one, and the `merge` operator will unsubscribe from all source observables if one of them emits an error.

Comment: Just make sure that your process can handle unsubscription.

Comment: What about updates? If I make an `Observable<List<T>>` then I can read the progress of each download over time.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do

```
final List<Observable<T>> tasks = getTasks();
List<T> values = getTasks().stream()
                           .map(observable -> observable.firstElement().blockingGet())
                           .collect(Collectors.toList());
Observable<List<T>> result = Observable.fromArray(values);
```