# How can we get count of parameters passed in doInBackground(String... args)

Tags: android, string, parameters

I searched many posts I got meaning of **(String... args)** but now my problem is how can I get count of these parameters inside a function.
Any help is appreciated...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the ellipsis (...) for in this method signature?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2367398/what-is-the-ellipsis-for-in-this-method-signature)

Comment: Please consider trying that "prior research" thing the next time.

Comment: You should try it on your own and then post your question. This doesn't show any effort.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `length` method. Basically its a `Array` so you can treat it as `Array`.

```
  public void doInBackground(String… args) {

    int count = args.length;

}
```

For getting value from index - you could use

```
String value = args[index];
```