# how to import a variable in Main class to a another class

Tags: java, android, plaintext

I have a class that send a message by socket and I want that the message, it's the text that the user put in the plain text that it's supposed to send. So I try to catch the message of the plain text in the class but it didn't work **if someone knows how to import a variable of the main class to another class.**

this is the code where I execute the class

```
    class client extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

                Handler handler = new Handler( );

                protected Void doInBackground(String... h) {


                    TextView t3;
                    final EditText send;
                    send = (EditText) findViewById( R.id.editText );
                    t3 = (TextView) findViewById( R.id.textView );

                    try {
                        handler.post( new Runnable() {

                            @Override


                            public void run() {
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"start client", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        } );
                        WifiManager manager = (WifiManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(WIFI_SERVICE);
                        ip = Formatter.formatIpAddress(manager.getConnectionInfo().getIpAddress());
                        String[] mess = h;
                        String messag_send=(mess+"<ip>"+ip);


                        sock = new Socket( "192.168.5.178", 5000 );


                        printWriter = new PrintWriter( sock.getOutputStream() );


                        printWriter.write(messag_send);


                        String line = "no";
                        printWriter.flush();
                        printWriter.close();
                        sock.close();
                    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();

                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    return null;
                }

and to  import 


 client client = new client();

            client.execute(h);
```

Comment: Give it as a [parameter to your AsyncTask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6053602/what-arguments-are-passed-into-asynctaskarg1-arg2-arg3).

Comment: thanks but when i ask to send a message it send [Ljava.lang.String;@7bab97d how can i change it to String text

Comment: This could be caused by several things. Either the argument you give to `printer.write()`(I assume that's what you use) **genuinely** contains this value, or you have declared your variable as an `Object` instead of a `String`. In the latter case, you should ensure you are dealing with `String` variables. In the former case, you have some investigation to do as to why this happens (you might be calling a `toString()` somewhere you're not expected to do it.

Comment: thanks, i will try to find the error and will let you know.

Comment: i didn't find the error i edit the code if you want to find the error. i you don't want because i need to ask another question i will understand. thanks if you try to find what his wrong .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see, you receive your variable `h` as a [vararg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2367398/what-is-the-ellipsis-for-in-this-method-signature). So `h` is really an Array of Strings.

```
protected Void doInBackground(String... h)
```

However, you don't really access its content, instead you write

```
String[] mess = h;
String messag_send=(mess+"<ip>"+ip);
```

Since `mess` is an array, you embed its `toString()` value in your message.

What you need to do instead is retrieving the first value of your array (which probably holds only one element anyway) like so

```
String mess = h[0];
String messag_send=(mess+"<ip>"+ip);
```

Comment: Glad I could help ;). Don't forget to accept this answer. This would help other users who have the same question.

Comment: Sorry i forget, I only knew this fonction today