# [Ljava.lang.String; cannot be cast to java.lang.String

Tags: java, variadic-functions

I have below code in my DAO  and it is returning a **[Ljava.lang.String; cannot be cast to java.lang.String exception**
I would like to know why this cause and a solution.

```
public Collection<Testdoc> findTestId(int idTest, String... testtype) {
    StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer("SELECT w FROM Testdoc w WHERE w.Test.idTest = :idTest");           
    buf.append("AND w.testtype IN ( :testtype ) ");         
    return findByQuery(buf.toString(), "idTest", idTest, "testtype ", testtype );
}
```

Comment: Why did you declare the second parameter as a `...` varargs parameter, if you don't know what it means/does? *Hint:* It makes the argument into an **array**. `[Ljava.lang.String;` is the internal class name for a `String[]`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the ellipsis (...) for in this method signature?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2367398/what-is-the-ellipsis-for-in-this-method-signature)

Answer (score 1):

The last argument of `findByQuery` appears to be of type `String`. You have used a `String[]`.

`String...` as the last parameter type indicates a `String[]` but allows the caller to use the likes of `fn("x", "y", "z")` instead of `fn(new String[] { "x", "y", "z" })`.

@user85421 points out that `findByQuery` may well be declared something like:

```
Collection<Testdoc> findByQuery(String sql, String... args);
```

In which case you may need to concatenate arguments, though that may still not be correct.

You would then need to concatenate arrays. In the absence of an `Arrays.concat`, see the question [How can I concatenate two arrays in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/80476/how-can-i-concatenate-two-arrays-in-java).