# How is varags usage in Room allowed?

Tags: java, android, android-room

I have pre-existing code which uses varargs to denote an incomming array of args. How does Room Database understand this?

```
@Insert
public abstract void insertData(Data... data);
```

Comment: i've edited your question to refer to [varargs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2367398/what-is-the-ellipsis-for-in-this-method-signature) instead, but if this wasn't what you meant, please feel free to rollback

Comment: inside the function, its visible as an `Array<Data>`